# Add Buttons Above the Notifications Tab in the Status Bar

Tags: android

I am developing an Android app that will run as a service most of the time. The user would be able to control it via the status bar -- including the ability to stop the service altogether.

Even though I am able to make a custom view and put buttons on the Notifications area [see Figure 1], I would like to be able to put it above the "Android"/Service Provider's name.  Much in the same way as the Music Player app does this [see Figure 2].  That way, even if the user clears their notifications, my app's control panel will remain active as long as the service is running.

What's the best way to do that, please?

[image: Figures 1 and 2]

[Original Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZV6j.png)

Comment: I've figured a way to add an ONGOING_EVENT flag via notification.flags = notification.flags | notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;  
But I'm still wondering how does the Media Player app solve that problem without the ongoing flag?

Comment: Is that a default music player of Android, you are talking abt ?

Comment: The music player in Figure 2 came with the ROM I'm using; so yeah. It looks like the default MP3 player that comes on the emulator is also using the FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT (see: http://i.imgur.com/mGJnN.png). I'm probably going to stick with that for now...

Comment: The ROM your using has probably had some patches to the notification area, I don't think that much customisation is possible without root on a stock ROM.

Answer (score 1):

Your ROM has hidden the `Ongoing` header; both the Music player and the hardware control widget use the `ONGOING_EVENT` flag to remain where they are (someone correct me if I'm wrong). Confirm this by loading your app onto your patched phone - the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) specifically names e.g. Music players (and other times your process is still going on in the background) as times when you should use this flag.

You might like to note that the same page recommends the `FLAG_NO_CLEAR` flag - if all you want is for it not to be cleared when the user clicks `clear notifications` (this is recommended for ongoing apps).